# How use more or less inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Okay, I have big list of servers and I wrote a bash script to enlist them. But the problem is that it scroll through the terminal.

I need a pagination view of those.

Is it possible to put more or less inside bash script?

```
say ,
1
.
.
.
1000
```

One page at a time.

I have this code:

```
Staging_Servers)

  echo " Staging server list should go here"
;;

UAT_Servers)

  echo " UAT server list should go here"
;;

Prod_Servers)

 echo " Prod server list should go here"
;;
```

And one of them have long listing.

Once I run the script it shows menu like below:

```
1) Jenkin_Servers   5) Prod_Servers        9) DB-Staging
2) Nagios_Servers       6) Proxy_Servers      10) DB-Prod
3) Staging_Servers      7) Dedicated_Servers
4) UAT_Servers          8) Shared_Servers
Please enter the required number :
```

Okay once I give the number to the prompt one of the menu has lot of items which scroll of the screen. I want to see it by one page at a time.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: `yourscript | less` is a cheating? ;)

Comment: I was trying to piping it though...not the same...am I not clear enough in my query??? @Buffen

Comment: @jim66 that will not work. In fact not that way...could you please re-read my post again?

Comment: @user212064 quick way: you can make a wrapper script: `sh yourOriginalScript.sh|less`

Comment: @user212064 It's not that the question isn't clear, it's just that it's a trivial problem and if you can't get it to work then maybe there's in fact some other thing that's the real problem. Could you post some code?

Comment: @Buffen My bash script menu look like this : 1) a 2)b and selecting 2 will enlist lots of host..and I put that inside "case" statement one by one.

Comment: @user212064 You're still not posting any *code*.

Comment: Staging_Servers)

  echo " Staging server list should go here"
;;

UAT_Servers)

  echo " UAT server list should go here"
;;

Prod_Servers)

 echo " Prod server list should go here"
;;
 one of them having long list

Comment: @user212064 Please edit the question instead, the code is quite unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Do you just want to know how to scroll one page at a time? You can pipe your script to `less` and use the `z` key to do that.

Comment: Thanks @Buffen! for editing options..but what is the solutions to the problem? Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can invoke more or less in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
cat file* | less
...
```

will start paginating output once it reaches the `cat` (or whatever command it is).

I used to write README files that had a first line consisting of:

```
#!/usr/bin/less
```

When you executed the README, it would paginate the README. Self paginating text files.

Answer (score 0):

Store your server list in a string or [array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), and echo the output through your *PAGER*, or explicitly through less. For example:

```
export PAGER='/usr/bin/less'
case $list_name in
    Staging_Servers)
        echo "${staging_servers[@]}" | "$PAGER"
        ;;
    UAT_Servers)
        echo "${uat_servers[@]}" | "$PAGER"
        ;;
    Prod_Servers)
        echo "${prod_servers[@]}" | "$PAGER"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Don't override the user's setting of PAGER, and only do this if output is to a tty: `if test -t 1; then P=${PAGER-less}; else P=cat; fi ... cmd | ${P}`  (let the user set PATH appropriately.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell For the purposes of this answer, one simply can't assume *PAGER* is set, and setting it here makes the answer self-contained. The OP can always hard-code less or more if he doesn't want to rely on *PAGER*. However, one *should* assume a tty/pty because it's a user-facing menu. My goal is not to solve every possible edge case; just the OP's stated objective. YMMV.

Comment: One should always honor when the user has set PAGER.  It is a common convention, and it is extremely annoying to be a user and run a script that overrides such things.  You do not need to solve every edge case, but honoring standard conventions is absolutely necessary, especially when answering introductory level quesitons.